# Duplicate POST requests from Load balancer or from client

Tags: post, duplicates, timeout, load-balancing, connection-timeout

My app server getting duplicate requests. We initially thought client call is timing out and sending duplicate request. But the duplicate requests are received in 25 seconds once and 49 seconds once. 
We have a load balanced server for Node which sends client request to Load balanced App server. So, we have load balanced servers at both Node and app layer(java). 
Can some one suggest how we can identify if load balancer sending duplicate requests?

Answer (score 0):

Those duplicate requests may be health checks that are performed by the LB.